# Module pattern or modularity

Tags: javascript

```
    (function() {
  var names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
               "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  provide({
    getDayName: function(number) {
      return names[number];
    },
    getDayNumber: function(name) {
      for (var number = 0; number < names.length; number++) {
        if (names[number] == name)
          return number;
      }
    }
  });
})();

show(getDayNumber("Wednesday"));
```

Now i am reading an eloquentjavascript.net and i found such module pattern there.
But i find it a little bit confusing, so can you explain to me why do we need to put this after our function - >() . It is to make it self invoking as far as i understand.
but why do we need to make it self invoking?

And the second question why do we need to put our function in brackets  `(function`  ) () .Is ii just syntaxis ?

Comment: Because otherwise, it will never run.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-construct-in-javascript 1) The trailing `()` before the `;` invoke the `function` immediately. 2) The other parenthesis around the `function` distinguish it as an *Expression* so it can be invoked immediately (`function` statements/declarations don't allow it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of immediately-invoking functions is twofold: firstly, most obviously, they invoke themselves immediately. Secondly, all variables defined within the function are encapsulated within that function.

For example:

```
(function () {
    var foo = "bar";
    window.bar = foo;
})();
```

After this function executes, `bar` will be accessible outside of the function, but `foo` will not.

As for enclosing the function in brackets, this causes the function to be treated as an expression, which can then be executed.

```
( function (a) { console.log(a); } ) ("foo");
```

In the above, "foo" will be logged. Without the brackets, you'll get a syntax error.

**EDIT**

It's also worth noting that you can use (and will occasionally see) `!function` instead of `(function)` to make the function an expression:

```
!function () {}();
```

Which is the same as

```
(function () {})();
```

With the exception that it converts the return value to a Boolean, which is negated, but ignored in most cases anyway.